# Run useEffect only if certain values are true, but don't re-run unless the dependencies change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I found similar questions where people wanted to run `useEffect` only if certain values are true, but the solutions are always along the lines of:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isTrue) {
    return;
  }
  someFunction(dep);
}, [dep, isTrue]);
```

The issue with this is if `isTrue` goes from true to false to true, it re-runs `someFunction`, even if `dep` didn't change. I want to re-run `someFunction` only if `dep` changes.

The only way I can think of to do this is a hack using refs, e.g:

```
function useEffectIfReady(fn, deps = [], isReady = true) {
  const ref = useRef({
    forceRerunCount: 0,
    prevDeps: [],
  });

  if (isReady && (ref.current.forceRerunCount === 0
    || deps.length !== ref.current.prevDeps.length
    || !deps.every((d, idx) => Object.is(d, ref.current.prevDeps[idx])))) {
    ref.current.forceRerunCount++;
    ref.current.prevDeps = deps;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current.forceRerunCount === 0) {
      return;
    }

    return fn();
  }, [ref.current.forceRerunCount]);
});
```

Is there a cleaner way? I don't like the idea of comparing dependencies myself, since React might change how they compare dependencies and AFAIK they don't export their comparison function.

Comment: Why don't you try different useEffect for isTrue & SomeFunction? It will run belonging states alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a ref as the gatekeepr

```
function useEffectIfReady(fn, deps = [], isReady = true) {
  const readyWasToggled = useRef(isReady);

  /* 
  There are 2 states:
    0 - initial 
    1 - ready was toggled
  */
  const getDep = () => {
    if (readyWasToggled.current) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (isReady) {
      readyWasToggled.current = true;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isReady) {
      return;
    }
    return fn();
  }, [...deps, fn, getDep()]);
}
```

[image: Edit optimistic-wu-cbfd5]

Comment: This is the same thing as  my first example, except without `isTrue` in the dependencies, so the function won't run when `isTrue` is flipped to true

Comment: I misread your intention then, I've updated my answer to show how `fn` will only run if `isReady` was true, but will not run again if flipped to back to true

Comment: I've made another update to my answer, now it actually works!

Comment: I see, that's pretty clever, why do you need the third state? I think just having the first 2 states should be enough

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this out - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly then the behaviour you're looking for is:

- if `isReady` becomes true for the first time, run `fn()`
- if `isReady` flips from false to true:

1. `deps` have changed since last time ready, run `fn()`
2. `deps` have not changed since last time ready, do not run `fn()`

- if `deps` change and `isReady` is true, run `fn()`

I worked this out from plugging your hook into some UI code, if it's not correct let me know and I'll change/delete this. It seems to me that `isReady` and `deps` do not have a straightforward relationship, as in they do not correlate well enough for a single `useEffect` to handle. They are responsible for different things and have to be handled separately. I would try and refactor things higher up in the logic so that they will play nicer together, outside the react render cycle if possible, but I understand that isn't always the case.

If so, using a gate and `refs` to control the flow between them makes the most sense to me. If you only pass one `dep` to the hook it makes things a bit simpler:

```
function useGatedEffect(fn, dep, isReady = true) {
  const gate = useRef(isReady);
  const prev = useRef(dep);

  useEffect(() => {
    gate.current = isReady;
    if (gate.current && prev.current !== null) {
      fn(prev.current);
      prev.current = null;
    }
  }, [isReady, fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    gate.current ? fn(dep) : (prev.current = dep);
  }, [dep, fn]);
}
```

However, if you have to pass in an unspecified number of dependencies then you are going to have to do your own equality checks. React will throw warnings if you try and pass spread objects to a `useEffect` and it's better for readability to have them hard-coded anyway. As far as I can tell this does the same thing as your original hook, but separates the (simple) comparison logic which will hopefully make it easier to refactor and maintain:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } = React;

function useGatedEffect(fn, deps = [], isReady = true) {
  const gate = useRef(isReady);
  const prev = useRef(deps);
  const [compared, setCompared] = useState(deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    depsChanged(compared, deps) && setCompared(deps);
  }, [compared, deps]);

  useEffect(() => {
    gate.current = isReady;
    if (gate.current && prev.current.length !== 0) {
      fn(...prev.current);
      prev.current = [];
    }
  }, [isReady, fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    gate.current ? fn(...compared) : (prev.current = compared);
  }, [compared, fn]);

  function depsChanged(prev, next) {
    return next.some((item, i) => prev[i] !== item);
  }
}

function App() {
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState("");
  const [string, setString] = useState("hello");
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

  const callback = useCallback(dep => {
    console.log(dep);
    setString(dep);
  }, []);

  useGatedEffect(callback, [saved], ready);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{string}</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setSaved(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setReady(!ready)}>
        Set Ready: {(!ready).toString()}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your query correctly, you need to execute the `someFn()` depending on the value of isTrue.

Though there are ways using custom hooks to compare old and new values and that can be used to solve your problem here, I think there is a much simpler solution to it.

Simply, removing the `isTrue` from the dependency array. This will make sure that your `useEffect` runs only when the `dep` changes. If at that point, i`sTrue == true` then nothing gets executed, otherwise your code gets executed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isTrue) {
    return;
  }
  someFunction(dep);
}, [dep]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the useEffect in this case for each state, just an idea based on your codes

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your codes here
  if (!isTrue) {
    return;
  }
}, [isTrue]);

useEffect(() => {
  // your another set of codes here
  someFunction(dep);
}, [dep])
```